# How to exclude particular bean from being refreshed in application context

Tags: java, spring

I want to exclude a bean from being refreshed when I call refresh method of configurable spring application context.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);

for(int i=0; i<MAX ; i++) {
    context.refresh();

    ...

    try {
        Thread.sleep(pause);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the bean into a different context file, i.e spring-static-context.xml and dont include it into your args array.